# How can i feed multiple arrays to a keras machine learning algorithm?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, tensorflow, keras

I am planning to make a premium charge predictor which predicts your insurance premium based on multiple factors which including gender, sex,BMI, etc.(6 of them in total) I have the data but I can't figure out how to feed multiple arrays to it.
Here is the code-

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from tensorflow import keras
import pandas as pd
a=0
file=pd.read_csv(r"""C:\Users\lavni\OneDrive\Desktop\proj.csv""",sep=',')
Age=pd.DataFrame(file,columns=['age']).to_numpy()
Sex=pd.DataFrame(file,columns=['sex']).to_numpy()
BMI=pd.DataFrame(file,columns=['bmi']).to_numpy()
Children=pd.DataFrame(file,columns=['children']).to_numpy()
Smoker=pd.DataFrame(file,columns=['smoker']).to_numpy()
Region=pd.DataFrame(file,columns=['region']).to_numpy()
Charges=pd.DataFrame(file,columns=['charges']).to_numpy()

Data=[Age,Sex,BMI,Children,Smoker,Region]

model=keras.Sequential([keras.layers.Dense(units=6,input_shape=[6])])
model.compile(optimizer='sgd',loss='mean_squared_error')

model.fit(Data,Charges)
```

Upon running this, it gives me the following error:

```
    ValueError: Layer sequential expects 1 inputs, but it received 6 input tensors. Inputs received: [<tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=int64>, <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:1' shape=(None, 1) dtype=string>, <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:2' shape=(None, 1) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:3' shape=(None, 1) dtype=int64>, <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:4' shape=(None, 1) dtype=string>, <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:5' shape=(None, 1) dtype=string>]
```

I understand the error, putting some research into it I get that it needs to be a tuple but despite changing it, it still gives the same error.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Several problems here,
First off, don't use `pd.DataFrame` for loading a single column of data (1d data) from a file. Use [`pd.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22.0/generated/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas.read_csv), optionally with a `squeeze` argument, if you only need to read a single column.

Next up, you can't use a python list for grouping several inputs, you must use a tuple, like this:

```py
Data = (a,b,c,d) # Not [a,b,c,d]
```

Otherwise, the keras models will try to feed your dataset `a` then `b` and so on instead of `[a[0], b[0], ...]`. Which seems like what you aim for.

Next, in your particular case, it seems like you don't need a multi input keras model. All you need is just the valid `input_shape` on your first layer. That's why the model is complaining. It expects a single input and you are trying to jam in 6 of them. Convert the inputs into a single array like

```py
data = dataframe.to_numpy() #dataframe must have 6 columns!
targets = targets.to_numpy() #single column
...
model.fit(data,targets)
```

Update your code with this info and ask me in case of additional problems.
Cheers!

Comment: Thank you very much,Ive changed the code to your requirement, but the error i get now is ```ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type int). ``` The model structure code being ```model.add(keras.layers.Dense(units=6, input_shape=(6,)))``` and one of the lists of the array being ```[19 'female' 27.9 0 'yes' 'southwest']```

Answer (score -1):

Write it in this manner:

```
model = keras.Sequential()
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(units=6, input_shape=(6,)))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(units=?))
```

The last layer is the output layer(as I don't know what your output looks like I couldn't define the units.)

Also one quick tip for you, you can reduce your code size by writing your code like this:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from tensorflow import keras
import pandas as pd
a=0
file = pd.read_csv(r"""C:\Users\lavni\OneDrive\Desktop\proj.csv""",sep=',')
Charges = file['charges'].to_numpy()

features = ['age', 'sex', 'bmi', 'children', 'smoker', 'region']
Data = file[features].to_numpy()
# it will convert all of your features into a numpy array

model = keras.Sequential()
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(units=6, input_shape=(6,)))
model.compile(optimizer='sgd',loss='mean_squared_error')

model.fit(Data,Charges)
```

Comment: Without having a look at your dataset it is difficult to say more than this. I have no idea what your output data looks like so it would be better if you could post the link of the dataset.

Comment: sure i can,I couldnt find the exactt same link but this is a project which involves the use of it. [link](https://www.kaggle.com/noordeen/insurance-premium-prediction)